# SharePoint 2010 Lotus Domino SSO

Tags: sharepoint-2010, single-sign-on

I'm near to approach to a new big project to introduce SP 2010 Standard to replace an existing intranet portal....and I have to make something like a feasibility study...

Users who access to the portal are surveyed in Active Directory and Lotus Domino and when the users click on link displayed in the portal.... in SSO mode they can open some lotus applications (using ltpa token).

So....in this beautiful environment I have to introduce SP2010! :-/

I have a couple of questions...

1. Is it correct to using Claims auth + FIM (ForeFront Identity Manager) + User profile serivces to allow SP 2010 to map more then 1 identity Provider? (in this case AD and Lotus Domino)
2. Based on your experience....how can I try to reproduce the SSO from SP page...to Lotus application?

thanks!!! :)